# Suppressing the "reason" for shutdown on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, shutdown

How can I suppress giving a reason for shutdown on a Windows Server host?

Specifically, on 2008 R2, but all versions back to 2003 and up to 2012 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You will need to modify the group policy that is applied to the servers. Open up the Group Policy Management Console and navigate to *Computer Configuration >> Administrative Templates >> System* and select "Display Shutdown Event Tracker." Disable that option.

Comment: I like (and had forgotten about) @[xeon](http://serverfault.com/users/10695/xeon)'s [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/560512/2321), but this is more inline with what I was hoping to find :)

Comment: The "Group Policy Management Console" can be opened via Win+R and then executing `gpedit.msc`.

Answer (score 23):

If you do not want to change via Polices you can always issue the shutdown command to avoid the question.

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

/s = shutdown
/t = time till shutdown 0 = immediely

Comment: +1, I do not get the downvotes, you answered the question perfectly.

Comment: +1, even though this may not be the permanent solution that OP had in mind, you are technically correct in that this does shut down without a prompt.

Comment: if you always shut the host down like this, then it is the permanent solution ;-)

Comment: I downvoted because I wrongly interpreted the OP to have explicitly wanted a one-time change that would permanently shut down the shutdown event tracker. I realize that this, while perhaps not what most sysadmins would consider to be a permanent solution, is still valid. Downvote retracted.

Comment: In actual fact, this more accurately answers OP's question which was how to *suppress* (not disable) the prompt.

Answer (score 17):

Running the following as an elevated admin:

```
reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability" /v ShutDownReasonOn /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

and then logging off and on again should to the trick.

This is quicker than using [group policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776766%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which you should use when you are in a domain and want to apply this change to many servers.

Comment: Not sure if this one is for pre-Windows 2012 R2, but on 2012 R2 this registry path is invalid and should be:

reg.exe add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability" /v ShutDownReasonOn /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Comment: @KoenZomers - You are correct, there was an extra 'control' in the path, 9 people up-voted and nobody noticed. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 9):

I'm sure the OP has found the other answers useful but future readers may be interested in a powershell version.  Works out of the box in 2008 or up, and maybe in 2003 if powershell is installed.

```
    if ( -Not (Test-Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability'))
    {
    New-Item -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT' -Name Reliability -Force
    }
    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability' -Name ShutdownReasonOn -Value 0
#
```

or a .reg file version.  Install with "regedit /s Disable_Shutdown_Event_Tracker.reg"

Disable_Shutdown_Event_Tracker.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability]
"ShutdownReasonOn"=dword:00000000
```